# Implement copy/deepcopy on multiple base classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, copy, polymorphism

not sure if this maybe is a codeReview post but here we go:

My goal is to re-implement the way objects are copied within our application. We have multiple base classes:

```
CoreList<T> // for all list classes
BasicReference // for all reference classes
CoreObject // for all "normal" domain objects
```

All classes inherit from these base classes. Right now the copy method is implemented on the `CoreObject` class and will go through the object tree via reflection, looking at each property type and select the correct way to copy the type and finally returning always `CoreObject`.

There are some problems which I don't like about that approach, which is why I would like to change it:

- After copying an domain object you always have to cast it "back" to the original type, for example: `Animal = animal.Copy() as Animal;`
- All logic to copy each type is within the CoreObject class even though it should not know about other base classes.

So my first attempt was to introduce a interface:

```
public interface IObjectCopy<out T>
{
  T Copy();
}
```

Which then should be implemented on all base classes. Then every class is responsible for the way it is copied. For example (pseudo code):

```
public class CoreObject : IObjectCopy<CoreObject>
{
  public virtual GerCoreObject Copy() 
  { 
    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
      if (prop.IsNoSimpleType)
      {
        (prop as IObjectCopy).Copy()
    }
  }
}
```

That solves the copy-responsibility problem, in addition inherited classes can take care of the copy logic themselves.

Unfortunately that does not solve the return type, I still have to cast it to the correct type. I did not think of a better solution to solve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem could be solved in OO using [covariant return types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type). Unfortunately C# does not support covariant return types like Java and C++, requiring it to always break type safety.

Without breaking type safety (casting) in C# this is unfortunately not possible.

Here are two possible options:

```
//explicit interface implementation
public class Animal : CoreObject, IObjectCopy<Animal>
{
    Animal IObjectCopy<Animal>.Copy()
    {
        return (Animal) base.Copy();
    }
}
//does not require an explicit cast
IObjectCopy<Animal> animalCopy = myAnimal;
Animal copiedAnimal = animalCopy.Copy();

//second option: shadow the original method and cast inside the object
public class Animal : CoreObject, IObjectCopy<Animal>
{
    public new Animal Copy()
    {
        return (Animal) base.Copy();
    }
}
Animal copy = myAnimal.Copy();
```

Another option using bounded quantification:

```
public class CoreObject : IObjectCopy<CoreObject>
{
    public CoreObject Copy()
    {
        return Copy<CoreObject>();
    }

    protected T Copy<T>()
        where T : CoreObject, new()
    {
        T t = new T();
        //implement copy logic:
        return t;
    }
}

public class Animal : CoreObject, IObjectCopy<Animal>
{
    public new Animal Copy()
    {
        return Copy<Animal>();
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, C# now supports covariance (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee207183.aspx). And @derape even using it in his question

Comment: @Archeg but not covariance in return types!

Comment: Do you mean without generics? Yes, but with generics you can do most of it (for example like in the solution I've proposed). It may look a bit more complex though

Comment: @Archeg like the example on the wikipedia link

Comment: Possible with generics. C<T> where T : A and D : C<B>. Then getFoo() will return A for C and B for D

Comment: I ended up with our second solution, because there is not so much refactoring necessary for us. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, you need [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

```
public class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T>
{
     public virtual T Clone()
     {
         // Perform cloning with reflection.
         return clone as T;
     }
}
```

Then you just define your class as:

```
public class EndObject : BaseClass<EndObject>
{
}

EndObject e;
e.Clone() // Will return EndObject type
```

Comment: +1, but be careful: this requires a significant breaking change to the API just to support cloning without casting.

Comment: I agree with @BasBrekelmans. It works well if your hierarchy is simple, if it is very complicated and generic - you might happen to over-complicate it.

Comment: I really liked that solution, but unfortunately our API is quite complex and it would require massive refactoring to adapt it to generic classes :-(